# how to track active and idle time of desktop using javascript in (Tauri desktop cross platform application)

Tags: javascript, desktop-application, rust-cargo, tauri

Im able to track the user idle time of desktop when the application is minimized(Tauri)

Im developing tauri desktop application using html, css, javascript for development. i want to track down the idle and active time of user.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[desktop idle](https://github.com/bithavoc/node-desktop-idle#desktop-idle) is something you can use. It's good for Tauri as it has cross-platform support for Win, Linux and MacOS.